# Finding multiple customer metrics such as new/old/repeat in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I want to identify multiple cohorts of customers in my data but I am facing a lot of difficulty in doing so. The data looks like this:

```py
date                                order_id   email

2021-01-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00    123        123@gmail.com   
2021-01-01 00:21:51.574000+00:00    124        abc@gmail.com
2021-01-01 02:52:50.862000+00:00    125        def@gmail.com
...                                 ...        ...
2022-07-21 06:14:13.419000+00:00    999        xyz@gmail.com
```

I want to find the following metrics and save them in different series:

1. old customer: if they have 1 purchase in the previous 12 months
2. new customer: if their first purchase is in the previous month
3. repeat customer: if they have more than 1 purchase in the previous 12 months
4. dead customer: if they have not made a single purchase in the previous 12 months
5. recovered: a dead customer made a purchase in the current month

An order id is a representation that a sale has been made so that's the column to use to count purchases. I have tried to first time differences between each order

```py
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby(['email'])['date'].diff()
```

But I am stuck and can't figure out what to do ahead. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I want to save each metric as a separate series so something like

```py
new_cust 

0                    123@outlook.com
1                    abc@gmail.com
2                    def@gmail.com
Name: email, Length: 3, dtype: object 

old_cust
0                    xyz@gmail.com
Name: email, Length: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: you must provide a fully reproducible minimal example (input + output), and ideally your attempt to try to solve the problem, here you just have a specs list… this is not how SO works

Comment: okay let me edit

Answer (score 1):

I can see many logics are there. I have made a tested solution for old, repeat, dead customers. As I dont have the data file, I created the data manually. And also note that you have to format date first like my code. Please check out the full solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
#creating data
df = pd.DataFrame([["2021-10-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",123,"user@gmail.com"], ["2021-05-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",123,"xyz@gmail.com"],
                   ["2022-07-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",124,"abc@gmail.com"],["2022-07-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",124,"abc@gmail.com"]], 
                  columns=['date', 'order_id','email'])
#formatting date column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date

#creating empty lists
old_customer=[]
new_customer=[]
repeat_customer=[]
dead_customer=[]
recovered_customer=[]

for i in df.email.unique():
    #filtering time
    df_temp=df[(df.date <= pd.to_datetime('now')) & 
        (df.date >= pd.to_datetime('now')- pd.DateOffset(months=12))]
    #filtering user
    df_cust=df_temp.loc[df_temp.email==i]
    #old customer logic
    if len(df_cust)>0:
      old_customer.append(i)
    #repeat customer logic
    if len(df_cust)>1:
      repeat_customer.append(i)
    #dead customer logic
    if len(df_cust)==0:
      dead_customer.append(i)

print("old customers list")
print(old_customer)

print("repeat customers list")
print(repeat_customer)

print("dead customers list")
print(dead_customer)
```

Output:

```
old customers list
['user@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com']
repeat customers list
['abc@gmail.com']
dead customers list
['xyz@gmail.com']
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hey I like the logic you've used but I have approx 500k rows in my dataframe and iterating through the entire thing is going to take roughly 72 hours according to ```tqdm```. Would you have a faster solution perhaps?

Comment: Hi, I think there wont be 500k iterations as I iterated by using unique users in "email" column. But yes, that would be the worst case if all 500K users are unique. I would suggest you to check the exact running time according to your data (You can use colab/cloud service like AWS). And I will try to share if I can generate a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is the alternative and faster solution to the previous one. Hope this will help you more. Thank me later :D

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
#creating data
df = pd.DataFrame([["2021-10-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",123,"user@gmail.com"], ["2021-05-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",123,"xyz@gmail.com"],
                   ["2022-07-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",124,"abc@gmail.com"],["2022-08-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",124,"abc@gmail.com"],
                   ["2022-08-01 00:20:01.733000+00:00",124,"use102@gmail.com"]], 
                  columns=['date', 'order_id','email'])
#formatting date column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date

#creating empty lists
old_customer=[]
new_customer=[]
repeat_customer=[]
dead_customer=[]
recovered_customer=[]
#filtering date
df_temp=df[(df.date <= pd.to_datetime('now')) & 
        (df.date >= pd.to_datetime('now')- pd.DateOffset(months=12))]

#11 months data before current month
df_temp_eleven=df[(df.date <= pd.to_datetime('now')- pd.DateOffset(months=1)) & 
        (df.date >= pd.to_datetime('now')- pd.DateOffset(months=11))]
#current one month data
df_temp_current=df[(df.date <= pd.to_datetime('now')) & 
        (df.date >= pd.to_datetime('now')- pd.DateOffset(months=1))]


#all customers
all_customer=df['email'].unique().tolist()

#old customer
old_customer=df_temp['email'].unique().tolist()

#new customer
#Finding users who are in current month but was not 11 months before current month
df_new = df_temp_current.merge(df_temp_eleven.drop_duplicates(), on=['email','email'], 
                   how='left', indicator=True)
df_new=df_new.loc[df_new['_merge']=='left_only']

new_customer=df_new['email'].unique().tolist()


#repeat customer
repeat_user_counts = df_temp['email'].value_counts()
repeat_customer = repeat_user_counts[repeat_user_counts > 1].index.tolist()

#dead cusstomer
dead_customer = list(set(all_customer) - set(old_customer))




print("old customers list")
print(old_customer)

print("new customers list")
print(new_customer)

print("repeat customers list")
print(repeat_customer)

print("dead customers list")
print(dead_customer)
```

Output:

```
old customers list
['user@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com', 'use102@gmail.com']
new customers list
['use102@gmail.com']
repeat customers list
['abc@gmail.com']
dead customers list
['xyz@gmail.com']
```